# JNDI LDAP logged user information

Tags: active-directory, ldap, jndi

Is it possible to get informations about myself? I want to make connection to LDAP and than get my informations as sAMAccount name, ... without DirContext search.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Answer is NO as there is not real session built on ad side.

Answer (score -1):

We have several [JNDI Code examples](https://bitbucket.org/jwilleke/examples/src/91c2df9b5481/Examples-JNDI/src/com/willeke/samples/ldap/jndi/?at=master) which show how to perform various searches.

Comment: Err, 'without `DirContext` search'?